# SQL Update Column on new Datarow

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, procedures

I've a MySQL server and I'm running a WebShop on it. Is it possible to calculate the sum of all articles on an order. Now when I add a new row I have to call a method in my PHP Script to calculate the sum. Is this possible to automate in MySQL (ex. Procedures)?

With Best Regards
Kevin Horvat

Comment: sum of means total no. of articles??

Comment: My SQL Query looks like:
SELECT SUM(tbl_articles.price) FROM ztbl_articles_orders
INNER JOIN tbl_articles ON ztbl_articles_orders.articleID = tbl_articles.articleID
INNER JOIN tbl_orders ON ztbl_articles_orders.orderID = tbl_orders.orderID
WHERE tbl_orders.userID = 3;

Comment: Now i want to save the result of the query and update another row in an other table with this result :) Is this possible?

Comment: yes you can do this...

Comment: it would be helpful if you show me your php code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="SELECT SUM(tbl_articles.price) as sum FROM ztbl_articles_orders INNER JOIN tbl_articles ON ztbl_articles_orders.articleID = tbl_articles.articleID INNER JOIN tbl_orders ON ztbl_articles_orders.orderID = tbl_orders.orderID WHERE tbl_orders.userID = 3;";
$result= mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH);
$sum=$row['sum'];
```

"$sum" gets the value you want, now you can insert or update with this value.

Comment: Yes that Worked very well. Thanks very much :)